# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - Allowing branch selection at release time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I have a Release pipeline (Classic version) with artifact set to a Azure Git repo. The `default branch` is set to `master` branch. Every time someone creates a new release, latest version of master branch is copied to the Dev Ops agent and release tasks will run.

Is it possible to allow specification of branch at release creation time?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you would like to trigger release pipeline with specific branches.

You could try to add **Branch filters**.

> A release will be triggered only if the Git push contains a commit on
> the specified branch. For example, selecting "master" will trigger a
> release for a Git push which contains one or more commits to the
> master branch. To trigger a release for any commit to branches under
> features/, enter "features/*". To trigger a release for commits to all
> branches, enter "*". Note that all specified filters will be OR'ed.
> For example, an artifact matching at least one filter condition would
> be sufficient to trigger a release.

[image]

If you mean triggerring stages with specific branches, **Artifact filters** can do.

[image]

For more information, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops).